# Error in reading in txt file in R: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)

Tags: r, txt

I am trying to read in this data: [http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/~swcheng/Teaching/stat5410/data/wastes.txt](http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/%7Eswcheng/Teaching/stat5410/data/wastes.txt)

But I keep getting error message from R, how can I fix it?

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
```

Comment: How are you reading the data? This works just fine: `data.table::fread("http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/~swcheng/Teaching/stat5410/data/wastes.txt")`

Comment: I think you're using `read.table`; if you add the argument `fill=TRUE`, then it finishes the loading. But what you get out of this is slightly wrong as well. See
`read.table("http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/~swcheng/Teaching/stat5410/data/wastes.txt", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE)`

Comment: @Roland @Mossa I am using `read.table` to input my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the last-row contains a weird symbol. Let us examine this:

```r
library(readr)

wastes <- read_table("http://www.stat.nthu.edu.tw/~swcheng/Teaching/stat5410/data/wastes.txt")

wastes %>% 
  tail()

#' Last value loaded is junk. Discard it;
#' 
wastes <- wastes %>% 
  slice(-n())
wastes
```

I'd just do this.